# Lectura de archivos XML con Symfony Crawler

Tags: php, xml, symfony

Tengo el siguiente código para abrir un fichero XML y cargarlo en el
[Crawler de symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-filtering)

```
$destino = "/media/samba/CDN/".$nombre;
$content = file_get_contents($destino);
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addXmlContent($content);
```

El contenido de mi fichero XML viene a ser así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <DesAdv>
        <Document Type="DesAdv" Version="2.0" />
            <DesAdvHeader>
                <DesAdvId>215954</DesAdvId>
...
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para acceder al contenido de `DesAdvId`?

He probado de usar esto, pero me devuelve un objeto igual de tipo *Crawler* y yo lo que necesito es acceder a esos campos...

```
$crawler->registerNamespace('contenido', $destino);
dump($crawler->filterXPath('//contenido:DesAdv/Document/DesAdvHeader/DesAdvId'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar el contenido de ese nodo, una vez hayas filtrado lo que necesitas, usar la función `text`. [Acceder contenido del nodo](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values)

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$texto = $crawler->filterXPath('//contenido:DesAdv/Document/DesAdvHeader/DesAdvId')->text();
```

En caso de que recibas varios nodos al hacer el filtrado, puedes recorrerlos utilizando un bucle y dentro gestionarlos de la misma manera con el `text`.